# Ansible extract only IP from pre-loaded ansible variable

Tags: module, ansible, ip

I have tried to extract only the IP from the variable `"{{ ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }}"` without success. This is returning me `['192.168.1.1']`.

I need to remove the `"[' ']"` with the ansible variable, to add only the IP to a file with the `lineinfile` module.

Comment: [I can't reproduce your problem](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/06fd1f76c8f2b06dd7bef6b5f30741f4). Note: I'm almost sure that your variable always returns a string and that the list notation you have above is an artifact of the way you debug that value. Meanwhile if I'm wrong and it is really a list, all you have to do is take the first element of the list (i.e. `{{ ansible_eth0.ipv4.address | first }}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The variable return me exactly ['192.168.1.1']. If I put your variable, it returns me ['1']. Only need the IP 192.168.1.1.

Comment: This I am not able to reproduce your problem, can you provide your playbook together with all necessary debug output?

Comment: `The variable return me exactly ['192.168.1.1']`. No. This is the output you have on screen (or else you are building a list somehow in your code). But the fact your only get `1` when using `first` is a clear confirmation that is contains a string. If you use the exact playbook I proposed in my non-reproducibility example, you will get the expected result. And if you still have problem problem, you need to [edit] your question and make it a clear [mre] with a complete playbook and a proof run of you get exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, they guys are right, I think you just wrong to output an ansible variable. Using builtin `debug` module, you will get the IP address only not in list. Example playbook:

```
---
- name: write out ansible_ens192.ipv4.address value
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
  - name: Print the IP address
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: "IP address is: {{ ansible_ens192.ipv4.address }}"
```

will produce this output:

```
PLAY [write out ansible_ens192.ipv4.address value] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Print the IP address] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "IP address is: 10.0.1.7"
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

which looks like OK.

But, if I "hack" your variable into list, and try to write it out:

```
---
- name: write out ansible_ens192.ipv4.address value
  vars:
    ipaddr:
      - "192.168.1.1"
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
  - name: Print the IP address in a list
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: "IP address is: {{ ipaddr }}"

  - name: Print the IP address sanitized
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: "IP address is: {{ ipaddr | join }}"
```

then with a simple `join` will solve your problem. The output will be:

```
PLAY [write out ansible_ens192.ipv4.address value] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Print the IP address in a list] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "IP address is: ['192.168.1.1']"
}

TASK [Print the IP address sanitized] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "IP address is: 192.168.1.1"
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```